# Can Spring @Autowired inject a non-implemented Interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm trying to understand the code from a simple spring boot REST api. I understand that spring can provide dependency injection with @Autowired, but what happens when you use @Autowired on an Interface that hasn't been implemented? What type of object is spring providing?

Below in class 1 RoomController has an @Autowired RoomRepository. What / how is spring injecting to roomRepository? Can spring instantiate interfaces somehow? Is the interface just a placeholder to use @Repository on a CrudInterface? Whats going on here? (This code runs fine btw)

Classes:

1.)

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LearningSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LearningSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/rooms")
    public class RoomController{
        @Autowired
        private RoomRepository roomRepository;

        @GetMapping
        public Iterable<Room> getRooms(){
            return this.roomRepository.findAll();
        }

    }

}
```

2.)

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Long> {
}
```

3.)

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ROOM")
public class Room {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ROOM_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long roomId;
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String roomName;
    @Column(name="ROOM_NUMBER")
    private String roomNumber;
    @Column(name="BED_INFO")
    private String bedInfo;

    Getters and Setters here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what happens when you use @Autowired on an Interface that hasn't been implemented?

If you put @Autowired on a non-implemented interface, Spring will throw an error. You need to have an implementation to use the annotation @Autowired.

Here you do not see any implementation, but there is one. When you will build this app (mvn package or a higher maven goal), the annotation @Repository with CrudRepository<Class, Id> will generate automatically an implementation of RoomRepository.
It is this implementation which will be provided to the @Autowired in your first class.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see anything about this in the docs for either @Repository or CrudRepository. So the generated implementation is prompted from the combination of the two? Is this because of how the container works? Can you point me some direction to read up more on this?

Comment: I can really redirect you anywhere else fom the spring documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.4.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) because I learnt spring mainly in my job from another colleague.

I think that the generation is prompt from the annotation and a CrudRepository's parent class/interface because this last one is not the only one you can use